# Linux System call for graceful reboot

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, reboot

I am instrumenting our Embedded Linux system for GCOV. Currently, there are places in the code where reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART) is called and that abruptly reboot the firmware. I need to be able to gracefully shutdown each user space process and then reboot the firmware. Is there a system call that I can call instead of reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART) that will call do this by essentially call each applications init script with the stop parameter? for e.g. "/etc/init.d/myapp stop"

Comment: As I understand, you should init system rather than system call. Like `init 6`. See `man init` for details.